# Spark: better single or separated filters?

Tags: apache-spark

I have different conditions to apply in a filter. Is there any concrete advantage to split them in separated filters from the performance point of view?

To be clear it is better:

filter (condition1 && condition2)

Or

filter (condition1).filter(condition2)

?

Comment: As said @abalcerek, every narrow transformation, will be pipelined into the same task, so the execution of the filters will happen in the same executor thus allowing local computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one filter after another will be grouped by spark into one stage anyways so it will be as efficient as putting everything into one filter.

Only reason I can see to split operation in to two consecutive filters is for readability and separation of concerns. But I guess you can do it by using separate function for your conditions.